# jQuery not creating links in IE/Chrome, works in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery 1.4.1 to parse an XML document and construct a list of links based on the content of this XML.  So far I have this all working quite well in Firefox.  However, when I view the same page in IE and Chrome, I see the `<div>` and `<li>` elements created, but the `<a>` elements do not appear.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple but after looking at this for a while now, I'm not seeing it.

HTML/JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#result").ajaxError(function () {
            $(this).text("An error occurred while retrieving the site map");
        });

        // Get the site map XML
        $.get("SiteMap.xml", function (data) {
            // The div element that will contain our menu
            var menu = $("#menu");

            // Iterate over each <Group> element
            $(data).find('Group').each(function () {
                // Create a new div to contain the current group
                var group = $("<div>").text($(this).attr("name"));

                // Create a new list for the current group
                var list = $("<ul>");

                // Now iterate over the <Page> elements contained in the current <Group> element
                $(this).find("Page").each(function () {
                    // Note that since we're doing a nested each(), the context of $(this)     changes
                    // Create a list item and a link for the current page, append to the list
                    var item = $("<li>");
                    var link = $("<a>").attr({ href: $(this).attr("url"), text: $(this).attr    ("title") });

                    item.append(link);
                    list.append(item);
                });

                // Append the list to the group's div and then append the group to the menu
                group.append(list);
                menu.append(group);
            });

            $("#result").text("jQueryDemo Site Map");
        });
    });       
</script>
    <body>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The XML that is being parsed is the following:

```
<SiteMap>
    <Group name="Selectors">
      <Page url="SelectById.htm" title="Select By Id" />
      <Page url="SelectByCss.htm" title="Select By CSS Class" />
      <Page url="SelectByElement.htm" title="Select By DOM Element" />
    </Group>
    <Group name="Events">
      <Page url="Bind.htm" title="Bind" />
      <Page url="Change.htm" title="Change" />
      <Page url="Click.htm" title="Click" />
      <Page url="Hover.htm" title="Hover" />
    </Group>
    <Group name="AJAX">
      <Page url="Ajax.htm" title="Ajax" />
      <Page url="AjaxError.htm" title="Ajax Error" />
      <Page url="Get.htm" title="Get" />
    </Group>
    <Group name="Animation">
      <Page url="Fade.htm" title="Fade" />
      <Page url="Slide.htm" title="Slide" />
    </Group>
    <Group name="DOM Manipulation">
      <Page url="Append.htm" title="Append" />
      <Page url="AppendTo.htm" title="AppendTo" />
      <Page url="Clone.htm" title="Clone" />
      <Page url="Each.htm" title="Each" />      
    </Group>
</SiteMap>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but how is this any easier than just coding out the HTML for the menu? You literally have more JavaScript code than you'd have HTML just to code the menu by hand.

Comment: This isn't actually production code, it was for a demo to show of jQuery capabilities.  That being said, this isn't such a far fetched scenario.  It's obviously quite common for a web page to use data retrieved from an external data source rather than hard coding the data in as you proposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'text' is not an attribute of an anchor tag, its a child TextNode element. @scald's solution should work as `link.append($(this).attr("title"))` creates the text in the correct spot.

You could also change:

```
var link = $("<a>").attr({ href: $(this).attr("url"), text: $(this).attr    ("title") });
```

to:

```
var link = $("<a>").attr({ href: $(this).attr("url") }).text($(this).attr    ("title"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this on a local file system or through a web server?

Chrome's developer tools reports:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file://localhost/Users/scald/Desktop/SiteMap.xml. Origin null is
>   not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

when I try to run it on the local file system, but when I move it to a web server it loads the elements correctly. Firefox worked on the local file system, though.

I also had to modify the link generator a bit to get the actual link text to display in Chrome:

```
// Now iterate over the <Page> elements contained in the current <Group> element
                $(this).find("Page").each(function () {
                    // Note that since we're doing a nested each(), the context of $(this)     changes
                    // Create a list item and a link for the current page, append to the list
                    var item = $("<li>");
                    var link = $("<a>").attr({ href: $(this).attr("url")});
// Append title to link separately 
                    link.append($(this).attr("title"));

                    item.append(link);
                    list.append(item);

                });
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I was running this via the Visual Studio development web server.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#result").ajaxError(function () {
                    $(this).text("An error occurred while retrieving the site map");
                });

                // Get the site map XML
                $.get("SiteMap.xml", function (data) {
                    // The div element that will contain our menu
                    var menu = $("#menu");
        var xmlData = $(data).find('SiteMap').first();
                    // Iterate over each  element
                    $(xmlData).find('Group').each(function () {
                        // Create a new div to contain the current group
                        var group = $("").text($(this).attr("name"));

                        // Create a new list for the current group
                        var list = $("");

                        // Now iterate over the  elements contained in the current  element
                        $(this).find("Page").each(function () {
                            // Note that since we're doing a nested each(), the context of $(this)     changes
                            // Create a list item and a link for the current page, append to the list
                            var item = $("");
                            var link = $("").attr({ href: $(this).attr("url"), text: $(this).attr    ("title") });

                            item.append(link);
                            list.append(item);
                        });

                        // Append the list to the group's div and then append the group to the menu
                        group.append(list);
                        menu.append(group);
                    });

                    $("#result").text("jQueryDemo Site Map");
                });
            });
```